# how to swap Integer type in java

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

How can i change swap the values of `i,j` in `swap2()` function:

```
enter code here public class pass_by_ref {
        public static void swap(Integer i, Integer j)  //this will not change i j values in main 
        {
        Integer temp = new Integer(i);
        i = j;
        j = temp;
        }
        public static void swap2(Integer i, Integer j) 
        {
        i = 20;   //as i am setting i value to 20 why isn't it reflected in main and same for j
        j = 10;
        }
        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
        {
        Integer i = new Integer(10);
        Integer j = new Integer(20);
        swap(i, j);
        System.out.println("i = " + i + ", j = " + j);
        swap2(i, j);
        System.out.println("i = " + i + ", j = " + j);
        }
        }
```

Outputs:

```
        i=10,j=20
        i=10,j=20;
```

I think that `Integer i=new Integer(10)` creates an object `i` with value 10,so when i write `i=20;j=10` in `swap2()` i am setting there values!..so why isn't it working
     i know that `swap()` will not change `i,j` values but why isn't `swap2()` not working?
     Well what change to make in `swap2()` so that the values are swapped.

Comment: You can't. Java is pass by value. Writing a method to do that is impossible.

Comment: can i make an class with 2 Integer i and j ,and then make an object of that class and then swap values?

Comment: Yes you can do that, or you can use an array like in the answer. It works because arrays are mutable.

Comment: I once wrote a mutable wrapper class for such a problem, if you don't want to use an return array (for whatever reason) you could use this dirty trick.

Answer (score 2):

Java is **always** pass by value, and `Integer` is immutable and you can't update the callers reference. You can use an array (the values stored in an array are *mutable*). Because array is an `Object`, it's value is passed by the value of the reference to the array instance and you can thus modify the values in the array. Something like,

```
static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
    // error checking
    if (arr == null || i == j) {
        return;
    }
    if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i > arr.length - 1 || j > arr.length - 1) {
        return;
    }
    // looks good, swap the values
    int t = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = t;
}
```

and then you might call it like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = { 10, 20 };
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    swap(arr, 0, 1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

And then (in the output) the values *swap*.

```
[10, 20]
[20, 10]
```

Comment: ok thanks...But does "Integer i=new Integer(10) " creates an object or is it just like a primitive data type?

Comment: @rashik `Integer` is an immutable wrapper type in Java. Also, I believe that there is an instance pool in use to guarantee that `Integer(10)` == 10.

Comment: A "funny" trick to swap 2 integers without using a third variable: a=a+b;b=a-b;a=a-b;